# c# visual studio 2013 unable to connect to oracle database

Tags: c#, database, oracle, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

I have visual studio 2013 and oracle 11g

When I try to connect to the database I get the next errror:

*"Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.
This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit
Oracle client compoonents installed."*

I know there is an issue between the 64 bit visual studio and 32 bit Oracle client. But I am looking for a solution the whole day now and I can only find outdated posts on the internet about older versions.

I already tried to select "platform target: x86" in the build settings.

I also looked for a 64 bit version of the oracle client but that also failed a couple of times.

I Appreciate every help because I need this connection for a very important school project.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

you need install 64 bit oracle client

link: [Instant Client Downloads for Microsoft Windows (x64)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html)

instantclient-basiclite-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip (23,504,640 bytes)

as they said about installation

> Installation Steps:
>
> 1. Download the appropriate Instant Client packages for your platform. All installations REQUIRE the Basic package.
> 2. Unzip the packages into a single directory such as "instantclient".
> 3. Set the library loading path in your environment to the directory in Step 2 ("instantclient"). On many UNIX platforms, LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>      is the appropriate environment variable. On Windows, PATH should be
>      used.
> 4. Start your application and enjoy.

Comment: Well, I already tried that one but I don't know how to install that. It's a folder with a lot of files. I tried to run every .exe and .jar file but nothing seemed to start a install dialog or something.

Comment: try this one for Oracle 11g `instantclient-basiclite-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0.zip (23,504,640 bytes) : *Instant Client Package - Basic Lite: Smaller version of the Basic, with only English error messages and Unicode, ASCII, and Western European character set support (10.2 only) *`

Comment: The Instant client does not include any ODBC, OleDB or ODP.NET Providers. These you have to install on top of it (depending which one you use in your application). Regarding 32 bit vs. 64 bit Oracle Client check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100